# ASP.NET Routing and Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, url-routing

I have an ASP.NET website (not MVC) that has webpages in a folder, /users, that can't be accessed unless the user is logged in. In the /users folder, I have a web.config file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And in the website root, the web.config file has:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

When users requested a page in the /users directory, such as /users/myccount.aspx, all is fine. If they aren't logged in, they are directed to the login.aspx page and then returned to the originally requested page if successfully logs in. Works as expected.

However, now we've added ASP.NET routing and this no longer behaves the same way. Now, if a user requests http://mydomain.com/myaccount, which in turn is translated to /users/myaccount.aspx page as the HTTPHandler for that route, the user doesn't get directed to the login.aspx page to provide credentials.

Not sure how to handle this. Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer to my own question.

I had created a custom class that implemented the IRouteHandler interface. This worked just perfectly EXCEPT that I hadn't explicitly called into the UrlAuthorizationModule to determine if the current user was authorized to view the specific HTTPHandler (Page) for the requested route.

Therefore, the solution was to instead of implementing the IRouteHandler interface, I inherited from PageRouteHandler class and overrode the method I needed to so I could add our necessary custom code before calling into the PageRouteHandler.GetHTTPHandler method.

All is well in the world again! :)